How to hack a grid::grob object in R to change existing text or add new?
EDIT
I don't have the underlying counts, just the end values for proportions.

Original Post
I have summary data for set intersections that I wish to visualize with R.

Probability of A: 0.2
Probability of B: 0.1
Probability of A and B: 0.05
Probability of A or B: 0.29

To visualize the data, I use the package {eulerr}. See below. However, I wish to customize the appearance of the plot, but don't know how to hack the object.
library(eulerr)

p1 <- 
  euler(c("A" = 0.205, "B" = 0.137, "A&B" = 0.0513)) |> 
  plot(quantities = TRUE,
       fills = list(fill = c("lavenderblush2", 
                             "lightblue2", 
                             "lightsalmon")))



p2 <-
  euler(c("A" = 0.205, "B" = 0.137, "A&B" = 0.0513)) |> 
  plot(quantities = FALSE,
       fills = list(fill = c("#9195F6", 
                             "#9195F6", 
                             "#9195F6")))


p1


p2


Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.0.2

I know that it's a grid::grob object because:
grid::is.grob(p1)
# [1] TRUE

How could I tweak some parts of the plot, for example:

change the formatting of p1 values from float to percents:


add labeling on top of p2:




How are you getting A or B = 29%?

This value (and all other probs) is given.

But A or B is not 29%, is it ok?

I need that A or B will be labeled as 29%.

There is no need to hack:
# show percent and counts
plot(euler(c("A" = 0.205, "B" = 0.137, "A&B" = 0.0513)), 
     quantities = list(type = c("counts", "percent")))



We can use gridExtra to add extra text:
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

p1 <- plot(euler(c("A" = 0.205, "B" = 0.137, "A&B" = 0.0513)), 
           quantities = list(type = "percent"))

p1_lables <- textGrob("A or B 29%")
margin <- unit(1, "line")
grid.arrange(p1_lables, p1, ncol = 1,
             heights = unit.c(grobHeight(p1_lables) + margin,
                              grobHeight(p1) + 20 * margin))



Thanks but this isn't what I need. Please note the percent values are not as I specified in the top of the post. I played around with eulerr options and I see no other way other than hacking the grob object.

@Emman your p1 expected output % is inside the plot?

not sure I understand the question. could you explain?

@Emman you noted "change p1 values from float to percents:", this is exactly what I did?

I meant to change formatting, 0.205 to 20.5%, etc.

Thanks! But still – how can I change A from 52% to 20.5% as in my p1 example? Likewise, B should be 13.7% and A and B should be 5%.
